# Specify the outgoing IP adress for a client connection in Node.js

Tags: node.js

Is there a means by which I can specify the outgoing IP address for a client
connection when using Node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems at the moment the only solution is to use `_createServerHandle` function

```
var s = new net.Socket({ handle: 
net._createServerHandle(localAddress) }); 
s.connect(port, host, cb);
```

see [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/3f0635ba23d44a83/2f872928d548f019) on mailing list.

Comment: Thank you; very helpful. Do you know of a similar mechanism for TLS client connection?

Answer (score 0):

It is available since *[2013.01.11 Version 0.9.6 (Unstable)](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)* release, with `localAddress` option.

```
var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.fr',
  localAddress: '192.168.0.2',
};

var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```